# SSH: Disconnecting configuration [my-server ... ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Failure]

Tags: jenkins

I am really new to jenkins. I have the configuration which can be seen on the screenshot:

[image]

When I run the job, I get the following error message:

```
SSH: cd [my_folder/] 
SSH: OK 
SSH: put [my_file.jar] 
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [my-server ... 
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Failure]
```

what does that message mean and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may mean that you are out of disk space on the Jenkins server.

I found this bug ticket that led me down the right path:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49582

Although it is marked as fixed, however, I still see this error when my Jenkins server is out of space.